# SQL select statement confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to create a select statement that checks with two values but checks one with null, i created this so far,

```
string selectStatement 
    = string.Format(@"SELECT a, b, c 
                      FROM Table1 
                      WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND a = {0} AND b = {1}",
                    aValue, bValue);
```

But I am pretty sure it will not work as we can't have 2 ands in select statement, any idea;s please ?

Comment: You can have as many And as you need :)..and it looks fine to me

Comment: you get an AND! you get an AND! everybody gets an AND!!!

Comment: Forgot the quotes for A and B values?

Comment: Note that your SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  See **[this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547986/how-to-prevent-a-sql-injection-escaping-strings)** for help on how to prevent this.

Comment: Where did you have read about only one AND?

Comment: @Steve i don't remember to be honest, but it was in my mind

Comment: @MichaelBray thanks but values are integers :)

Comment: @user13814: It is still bad programming practice to use `string.Format` to create SQL queries.  I strongly suggest you learn *and use* parameterized queries.

Comment: ahh, i know that but i forgot to use them, I will use them now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many `AND`s in your `WHERE` clause as you like.

If `a` and `b` are string values then you need quotes around the values - though it'd be much better to use a parameterized query and avoid the [Sql Injection vulnerability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM Table1 
WHERE c IS NOT NULL 
AND a = @p0
AND b = @p1
```

Comment: ...unless OP uses parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @MichaelBray: How do you know?

Comment: because parameters don't require type delimiters...   you can say `WHERE Email=@email` without quotes, pass a string to  `@email` and it works fine

Comment: ...and now Mark just made my comment irrelevant.  haha  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for that not to work, what DB are you using?

If in doubt you can also add parenthasis:

(c IS NOT NULL) AND ((a = value) AND (b = value))