# i want to subtract a value from a table while adding those value in another table

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I am creating a GRN application using winforms.  I have 2 tables.

Table 1:  In hand stock
Table 2:  Sales

How can I subtract in hand stock from Quantity after a sale.    This is my code for data base inserting.  While adding these I want to subtract.

```
String SQL = "insert into Items_Sold values('" 
            + myobj.Invoiceno + "','"
            + myobj.Itemcode + "','"
            + myobj.Category + "','"
            + myobj.Itemname + "','" 
            + myobj.Qty + "','" 
            + myobj.Unitprice + "',' " 
            + myobj.Subtotal + "')";

        DBConnection mycon = new DBConnection();
        mycon.insertValues(SQL);
```

I tried

```
 {
        string SQL = "Update Stock Set Invoiceno='"
            + textBox_InvoiceNo.Text.Trim() + "', "
            + "Quantity='" + textBox_Qty.Text.Trim() + "',"

        DBConnection database = new DBConnection();
        int rslt = database.updatetValues(SQL);

        if (rslt > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Faild");
        }
    }
```

This is updating my database with new data.

Comment: Parameterize your sql queries.  SQL injection attacks are bad.

Comment: I can smell SQL injection

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: so wow to do that in proper way help me i am a new bee

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547986/how-to-prevent-a-sql-injection-escaping-strings this will help to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems.

SQL Injection (i.e., use parameters)

No transaction -- you absolutely should be actions like this in a transaction so that the you don't end up with a debit but not a credit.

You really should use this update code similar to this

```
update Stock set Quantity = Quantity - @delta and Quantity >= @delta
where ...
```

This avoid problems that avoid some possible concurrency related issues

MISTAKE should have been

```
update Stock set Quantity = Quantity - @delta 
where ... and Quantity >= @delta
```

Comment: Gary Walker i need some more explanation about updating.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add a WHERE-condition to the UPDATE to only update some (or one) record and not all. And you probably want to use something like

```
SET quantity = quantity - difference_value
```

where `difference_value` would be what you want to subtract.
I am not sure about the details, as you did not state how you can e. g. identify the record to update when subtracting.

Comment: i am making a invoice form so in that i if i make a sale it should be subtracted in my stock table while adding that same quantity in sold table finally i want to c remaining stock