# Specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: c#, email

I'm using a table (Table has the location and mail id's) to get the e-mail id based on which location we are selecting.

Trying to send the mail gives the following error:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Code:

```
public void sendmail()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select EmailID from Table where Location='"+Location.Text+"'",con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string EmpMail = "Test@gmail.com";
    string EmpMailTo = "cmd";

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(EmpMail, EmpMailTo);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    message.Subject = "Auto generated mail";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    message.Body = "Test mail for auto generation";
    client.Host = "Apprelay";
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 5):

```
string EmpMailTo = "cmd";
```

I'm pretty sure `cmd` is not a valid email address.

My psychic debugging skills tell me that it's on this line:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(EmpMail, EmpMailTo);
```

...and that it's a `FormatException` based on [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t.aspx).

Try making `EmpMailTo` a valid email address.

Comment: am using sql query to get the mail id from a table.Query: (sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("select EmailID from Location where Location='"+Location.text+"'",con)

Comment: @user2842413: No you're not, you're setting the email address to the string literal "cmd".  You never actually fetch a result from your SQL query.

Comment: If you use quotes it is a string. You need to execute the command and use the result.

Comment: @user2842413 `string EmpMailTo = "cmd";` sets `EmpMailTo` to the *string* `cmd`. `string EmpMailTo = cmd;` wouldn't really make any sense either though

Comment: oh okay. Then can u guys please give me the right solution for that am new for c#

Comment: @user2842413 You need to read up on how to actually fetch data from SQL properly. Start with reading the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Comment: @user2842413 Please also read about SQL injection... this is very important if you're going to be a developer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547986/how-to-prevent-a-sql-injection-escaping-strings

Comment: @user2842413 Yes, I told you this wouldn't work already. Like I said, you need to read about how to actually fetch data from SQL properly. Did you bother to read any of the links I sent you?