# how to avoid insert dummy row in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am generating a gridview in a horizondal way. Code works fine but a dummy row insert with name of column1 and column2. How can I prevent this  insertion?? My gridview code is

```
str = "select MachID,EmpCode from EmpDetails where EmpCode='" + empcode + "'";
DataTable dt = GetData(str);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add();
}
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dt2.Rows.Add();
    dt2.Rows[i][0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        dt2.Rows[i][j + 1] = dt.Rows[j][i];

    } 
}
gvOrders.DataSource = dt2;
gvOrders.DataBind();
```

My present o/p is

```
Column1    Column2
MachID     101
EmpCode    ABC
```

I want to prevent this column1 and column2 row. How can I do this??

My GetData function is

```
private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    String constr =        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: On a side note your sql is prone to sql injection read this to avoid the sql injection prone queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547986/how-to-prevent-a-sql-injection-escaping-strings

Comment: @ Coder of Code, Ya, its just a testing model thatsy I avoid parameterized query.

Comment: can you post your aspx code

Comment: you assign `dt2.Rows[i][0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;` so you store your columnName in dt2 and it will show up afterwards. - in case i misunderstood please clarify your problem!

Comment: @Coder of Code, just a gridview controller <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" >

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz, I have posted my output sample..There you can see column1 and column2. I do not want this. I think its my logic mistake but I could not find that mistake. Its my problem

Comment: Why are you adding `columns` for each `rows` in your `dt`? It is because of the first loop where you are adding `columns` for each `ROWS` in your `dt`. One more thing, try to add `BreakPoints` and `Debug` your code to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your code-behind try to set the row header visibility to false as follows:

```
gvOrders.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Else in your aspx-file you can add `ShowHeader="False"`  to your asp:GridView tag.

Comment: I couldnt find "RowHeadersVisible"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.rowheadersvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The thing 'Column1' and 'Column2' is printed when the two your for loops iterates for the first time, so just put a condition to add nothing to your rows when the first execution of respective for loops is done. - Laymen solution (easy to understand and implement)

Answer (score 0):

Code for Deleting duplicate rows in a data table dt

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.SequenceEqual(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray))
                    dt.Rows[j].Delete();
            }
        }
```

add these lines of code in between second and third line